# "Cannot find symbol" after type casting

Tags: java, casting

I'm having two Java classes. The first implements the following method:

```
@Override public void onView(Object o) {
    o = (Foo) o;
    o.bar();
}
```

The second class `Foo` provides the `bar` method.

The problem now is that I get the "Cannot find symbol" compile error on the `o.bar();` call.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I achive the call of the bar method?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `o` is a reference to an `Object`, not `Foo`. The cast works since `Foo` is a subtype of `Object`, like any other class, but `o` remains a reference to an `Object`.

What you want is `((Foo) o).bar();`

Answer (score 6):

`o = (Foo) o;`

change it to:

```
Foo f = (Foo) o;
f.bar();
```

it will work

Answer (score 5):

`o` is declared as `Object`.

Putting a casted instance into it doesn't change that; you can only call methods that exist on the variable's **compile-time** type.

You need to declare a new variable of type `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler tries to call a method in the Object class with this statement `o.bar();` because you have declared `o` as Object which is not available there resulting in *Cannot find symbol* compiler-error. you need something like this `((Foo) o).bar();`